# Advice for Github and Xcode Integration with Multiple People

Tags: ios, xcode, github

A friend of mine and myself are making an iOS mobile application using Xcode as our IDE. We will be using Github as our version control tool. I was curious if there is anything I should be careful with when starting to work on this project together? For example, should I be making a "team" so that our bundle identifier is available on both computers? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check the existing threads this question has been asked multiple times: https://www.google.se/search?q=xcode+work+in+team+stackoverflow&oq=xcode+work+in+team+stackoverflow&aqs=chrome..69i57.7000j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 , if none of the existing threads answers your question, then redefine your question and ask more specifically what you want to know other than the information provided. GL.

Answer (score 0):

Git was made for simplicity in the fact that, before git, Linus Torvalds (the creator) was sending packets directly to his coworkers when they we're working on the same project. It was the easiest thing to do at the time. After deliberation, git was created by using hashes as a means of containing the information of 1) what is the commit, and what tree / branch it created / used, 2) What was the file, who authored and committed it, and a timestamp for that, 3) what was in the files that we're added / being tracked and changed. Also, it worthy of a note to understand that when you have a copy of a git repo, you can essentially say that you have a master since every "copy" is the same. Even if someone made a castastrophic mistake of deleting everything, you can re-push someone else's copy onto the origin branch and have everything working like normal.

So with that information, git and github is a great choice for version control as it doesn't impact the files by any means, and in a general case, it is faster and easier to use. As for your XCode example, I would suggest you check out [this tutorial and explaination here.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/51351/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-7)

And once you've followed it, made a github repository for you and your team.